# C language: How to share a struct (or, if not possible, an array) between parent and child (forked) processes through IPC?

Tags: c, global-variables, process, fork, shared-memory

I googled this for the past two weeks and I didn't get any answer. This is what I have:

- A parent process, which creates a struct `myStruct` that is basically a linked list using pointers (if this is a major issue, I can accept to use a fixed size array instead).
- A fixed number of child processes created with `fork()` that need a read/write access to the struct (or array) created by the parent.

I don't know how to do in order to make the variable `myStruct` become shared between processes.

I tried to solve the problem using SysV IPC functions like `shmget()`, `shmat()`, etc... in order to allocate my variable in shared memory, but I don't know how to work with void memory pointers to read/write the values into myStruct.

Ideally, I would like to be able to use the dot notation `(myStruct.node)->attribute = value` in every process without having to deal with pointers, since I don't know how my struct is organized into memory.

Is that possible? Could some of you please help? Any help is REALLY appreciated.

Further note: I know using threads, pipes, sockets or things like that would be much easier, but this work is for academic purposes for which I have to simulate the presence of multiple independent processes.

Comment: What's wrong with casting (or even just assigning since it's C) a `void*` pointer to a pointer to your struct, then just using it. It's not much different from a pointer returned by malloc(). You'll have to synchronize access using semaphores, though.

Comment: "I don't know how to work with void memory pointers to read/write the values into myStruct." -- cast them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a shared anonymous mapping with:

```
p = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Then these pages will *not* be copied-on-write, but rather will be shared by all forked processes.

Note that you have to be careful with locking here. You can use standard pthread mutexes and condvars on the shared memory segment between processes if (and only if!) you use [`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html) and [`pthread_condattr_setpshared`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_condattr_setpshared.html) to mark them as shared between processes.

Note also that this technique maps a *fixed size* arena, and must be done *before forking*. How you manage the contents of the memory at `p` is up to you. It's nontrivial to create a resizable shared memory arena; if you want to go that route, I'd recommend posting a second question, as different approaches may be necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was getting tons of segmentation errors with shm and now using mmap the code is flawless.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to share memory across a fork is to use a `mmap()`ed region of memory. If you use an anonymous `mmap()` (with MAP_ANON and MAP_SHARED) to store your struct (array, whatever) instead of `malloc()`ed memory, it will be shared by the child process.

Comment: `MAP_ANON` is marked as deprecated in my copy of mmap(2) ... :)

Comment: @bdonlan, just because one should use `MAP_ANONYMOUS` instead, I think. Another way to avoid that is to first use `shm_open` to obtain a file descriptor, and then do an `mmap` with that.

Comment: `MAP_ANON[YMOUS]` is not specified by POSIX, though it exists on most historic and current systems, and it's necessary for allocating anonymous pages when you can't be sure a file descriptor is available. It's a shame POSIX doesn't just standardize it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I accepted the other answer because it is a little more detailed and precise, but I still highly appreciate your help. Bye!